# Having trouble catching variables from urls.py with views.py

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to capture 2 slugs/variables from a url, pass them to a view and then use the view to pass them to a template.

The relevant line from my urls.py:

```
url(r'^docs/(?P<ver>)[-\w]+/(?P<name>)[-\w]+/$', views.sphinxdoc),
```

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def sphinxdoc(request, ver, name):
    context = {'ver': ver, 'name': name}
    return render(request, 'sphinx-documentation.html', context)
```

I am trying to change the `src` url of an `<iframe>` based on the `ver` and `name` values like so:

```
<iframe src="{% static 'docs/'|add:ver|add:'/'|add:name|add:'/_build/html/index.html' %}"></iframe>
```

When viewing in the browser, I get an error saying `'docs///_build/html/index.html'` could not be found.  It seems like the template variables 'ver' and 'name' never get set and are therefore rendered as empty strings.  How would I allow for these variables to be set from the `views.sphinxdoc` function?

Comment: check `ver` and `name` variable in `def sphinxdoc`. may be variables pass empty to template!

Comment: This does seem true. If I manually set `ver = 'version-string'` and `name = 'name-string'` it gets passed to the template correctly...so is there something I am doing wrong when pulling those conditions in from the view function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `urls.py` like this:

```
url(r'^docs/(?P<ver>\w+)/(?P<name>\w+)/$', views.sphinxdoc),
```

Since the `name` slug could have "-"'s in it this won't quite work.  Instead I used this:

```
url(r'^docs/(?P<ver>[-\w]+)/(?P<name>[-\w]+)/$, views.sphinxdoc),
```

Comment: The parentheses placement was indeed what was causing issues.  I made a slight edit so that the regular expressions would capture "-" characters as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out and thought I would post the solution here for anyone else that might stumble into this problem.

I am not sure why, but when pulling in `ver` and `name` as a functional parameter, its variable type was not being set as `string`.  To solve this I just converted the variables to strings like so:

from django.shortcuts import render

```
def sphinxdoc(request, ver, name):
    ver = str(ver)
    name = str(name)
    return render(request, 'sphinx-documentation.html', {'ver': ver, 'name': name})
```

This fixed the issue.

Edit: Additionally, you can simplify by doing in-line string conversion...

```
def sphinxdoc(request, ver, name):
    return render(request, 'sphinx-documentation.html', {'ver': str(ver),
                                                         'name': str(name)})
```

Comment: While this worked (for some reason), the real problem seemed to be the parentheses placement in my urls.py.  See Hasan Ramezani's answer.